# combinatorial optimization: multiple upgrade paths with inventory constraints

Tags: optimization, graph, combinatorics

I'm playing a video game, and i want to make a program that calculates the globally optimal build/upgrade path towards a fixed 6 item goal.

Time, Cost, Inventory constraints, and effectiveness (short/mid/long-term) ratings are to be considered. Identifying local spikes in effectiveness are also welcomed, but optional. I don't know how to classify this problem, but i'm guessing its a type of graph search. The fact that multiple criteria are being optimized is making things confusing for me.

Problem details:

- There are 6 free slots in your bag to hold items.
- There are 2 classes of items: basic items, and composite items.
- Composite items are built/merged from basic items, and other composite items.
- If you have enough gold, you can buy a composite item, and its missing sub components, all at once, using only 1 inventory slot.
- The build path for various composite items are fixed, and many basic components are featured in more than one recipe.
- Gold is earned at a fixed rate over time, as well as in small non-deterministic bursts.
- Time is bounded: it increments in fixed ticks (seconds) and has a max value: 2400.
- There exists no more than 50 items, maybe less.

*So, thinking about the problem...*

### Tackling the gold/time issue first

We can either ignore the non-deterministic aspect, or use some statistical averages. Let's make life easy, and ignore it for now. Since gold, and time, are now directly related in our simplified version, they can be logically merged.

### Combinatorial expansion of feasible paths

A graph could be built, top down, from each of the 6 goal items, indicating their individual upgrade hierarchies. Components that are shared between the various hierarchies can be connected, giving branch decisions. The edges between components can be weighted by their cost. At this point, it sounds like a shortest path problem, except with multiple parallel and overlapping goals.

*Now the question is: how do inventory constraints play into this?*

The inventory/cost constraints, add a context, that both disables (no free slots; not enough gold), and enables (two items merged freeing a slot) various branch decisions, based upon previous choices and elapsed time. Also, the possibility of saving up gold and doing nothing for a non fixed period, can be optimal in certain situations.

***How does one expand all the feasible possibilities? Does it have to be done at every given step? How many total combinations are there? Does this fall under topological combinatorics?***

#### Update:

*Q: How does one expand all the feasible possibilities?*

- The item build path is a dependency graph. A correct evaluation order of the dependencies is given by the **topological ordering** of the graph. A graph may have more than one valid evaluation order.
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32400/all-possible-topological-orderings-of-a-graph/32417#32417

#### Update 2:

*Q: How many total combinations are there?*

- Seems that it has to be counted, and there is no numerical formula.
- Algorithim 3.2, Page 150, "On Computing the Number of Topological Orderings of a Directed Acyclic Graph" by Wing-Nig Li, Zhichun Xiao, Gordon Beavers

Pseudo-Code:

```
f(g) | vertex_count(g) == 1 = 1
f(g)                        = ∑ {f(g \ {v}) for all v ∈ deg0set}

deg0set = {vertex_in_degree(g,x) == 0 for all x ∈ vertices(g)}
```

Mathematica-Code:

```
f[g_/; Length[VertexList[g]] == 1] := 1
f[g_] := With[
    {deg0set = Select[VertexList[g], VertexInDegree[g,#] == 0&]},
    Sum[f[VertexDelete[g,v]], {v,deg0set}]
]
```

---

### Rating Effectiveness

If the above expansion produces less than a few billion possibilities, we can just exhaustive search using OpenCL/CUDA. I'm not sure what other options are available, since most graph search stuff seems to just solve for one criteria.

Comment: Right now the language is about 50-50 between the game and an actual cs problem. Could you please formalize it, abstracting the key features, or would it help to mention which game?

Comment: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Youmuu%27s_Ghostblade

If you see the recipe, it shows what items it builds from. Since you have 6 inventory slots you could buy 2 Long Swords, Brawlers Gloves. Then merge two Long Swords into a Brutalizer etc. All the items merge into one item that cant be upgraded further. You want to end up with 6 items that cant be upgraded any more, but follow a cost effective path that maximizes your damage output throughout the process.

Comment: It could well be in the realm of [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to walk down to establish max values at each end stage and element, (ie add your metric (dps or whatever) up as you walk down, Pruning any combinations that require you to have more slots then possible. Then walk backwards from the best sets of possible end options, (which should be fairly sparse), you should be able to limit it to only the best composite options), and always move in a way that takes you to the max. Then set a value equal to damage on each option,

Given that dps or whatever of basic and preliminary composite items is probably less then the final possible composite items, this will be naturally weighted towards effectiveness at the end stage, so you may want to adjust, or set a minimum.

Once you have that, you can figure out the gold costs for your options, and decide how to weight getting to things faster.

Then you can go through and establish gold costs. You need to decide if you want to wait and earn or not.  If not, then you want to measure the rate of dps increase as a function of time.  If so, I expect it's cheaper to buy the items after not playing, over all.

You are going to have to use your data and make some value judgements.